# How to Align the UISegment Text at the Centre

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uisegmentedcontrol

Hi have an App where in have to show UISegmentedControls but the text on the UISegment is coming out of the segment towards Left .How to algin the Text at the Centre of UISegmented Control?

```
optionControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:optionNameArr];                                
[optionControl setFrame:CGRectMake(ReportingPanelScrollView.frame.size.width/2.8+80, y_Val +x_Dis, 100, 30)];
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f];
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:font,UITextAttributeFont,[UIColor darkTextColor],UITextAttributeTextColor,nil];
[optionControl setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
optionControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBordered;

optionControl.tag = sectionHeader*2000+itemHeader+200;
NSString *tagStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",optionControl.tag];
[optionItemControlDict setObject:optionSelectedTextArr forKey:tagStr];
[optionControl addTarget:self action:@selector(OptionControlSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[ReportingPanelScrollView addSubview:optionControl];
[optionControl release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
optionControl.contentHorizontalAlignment=UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
```